# C# WPF DataGrid Сохранение

Tags: c#

Добрый день, вечер!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить элементы при добавлении в DataGrid и обратно их считать?
Я добавляю одну строку и хочу сразу сохранить, например в Properties.Setting

Comment: А что мешает при добавлении прямо сразу сохранять в Settings? Чем добавление в DataGrid отличается от, к примеру, вывода на консоль?

Comment: Остальной код. Это же не просто текст для консоли
Пример одной кнопки, которая там ходит по куче методам

string[] ipPort = TextBox_Address.Text.Split(':');
if (IsValidIPAddress(TextBox_Address.Text))
{
       MainWnd.AddServerToDataGrid(MainWnd.DG_FavoritesList, 
       ipPort[0], ushort.Parse(ipPort[1]));
       Close();
}

Comment: Ну, а почему бы после `MainWnd.AddServerToDataGrid` не положить строку в Settings?

Comment: Каким способом это нужно сделать?
В массив бы я еще сохранил ибо массив можно расширять с помощью кода, а тут в параметрах как нужно добавлять поля для того, чтобы туда сохранять.
Я только одну строку могу сохранить так.
А нужно, чтобы автоматически считалось, так как я не знаю сколько всего мне нужно сохранить. Может 950 строк, а может 500.

Comment: Ну положите в Settings `List<string>` какой-нибудь.

Comment: Это будет считаться как один объект? Спасибо, попробуем.